# I cannot put file with cfftp, any ideas why?

Tags: coldfusion, ftp

I am trying to create a function to upload two xml files to another website once a day, I can make a connection fine using this code

```
<cfftp action = "open"
username = "xxxx"
connection = "MyConnection"
password = "xxxx"
server = "xxx"
passive="yes"
secure="true">
```

but then when I try to put the file using this code

```
<cfftp 
action="putFile"
connection="MyConnection"
localfile="xxx"
remotefile="xxx">
```

then I get this error

```
An error occurred during the sFTP putFile operation. 
 Error: Permission denied. 

 The error occurred in xxxxx: line 13
11 :        connection="MyConnection"
12 :        localfile="xxxx"
13 :        remotefile="xxxx">
```

Additional background info is that I can upload via filezilla.

Comment: I suspect you also might need to do something with keys / fingerprints if you're making secure connections with CFFTP. I have no experience with this, so can't offer any specific guidance. I'll try to find someone who knows about all this stuff to give you a hand.

Comment: Like I said in my (now removed) answer: when solution A works and solution B doesn't, compare them. View your system's logs if the error is thrown locally (can your application access the file you're trying to upload?). View the FTP server logs to see why the server throws the error. Compare the traffic (yes there are ways, even if it's encrypted).

Answer (score 2):

Just use `passive="yes"` with the putFile operation:

```
<cfftp 
   action="putFile"
   connection="MyConnection"
   localfile="xxx"
   remotefile="xxx"
   passive="yes">
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at some code I wrote a while ago that uses cfftp, and my remotefile contains the full path.  Can you confirm if yours does this?

The error "permission denied" would make sense it if was trying to upload it into the wrong directory also.  Let us know how you go.

Comment: my remotefile does not contain the full path, I'm not sure I'll even be able to get access ot the full path of this server. I've been trying the correct directory, I can view the contents of it for instance.